# PHP email attachment not going through

Tags: email, smtp, php

Not sure what I'm missing here, must be something small.. I removed the SMTP/IP/SERVER stuff from the top.  I also don't know why SMTP is adding the boundary at the end with "--" at the end, that part I didn't include in body.  Server is EC2 Amazon Linux.

```
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 00:33:15 -0400
To: X@X.com
Subject: Customer Order #100002
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 222:functions.php
From: X@X.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-----=ee483485be490cf4afcc323ac23e7a53"

Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="ShippingLabel_100002.gif"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ShippingLabel_100002.gif"
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-----=ee483485be490cf4afcc323ac23e7a53

-------=ee483485be490cf4afcc323ac23e7a53--
```

Comment: is your attachment under the allowable size?

Comment: i'm assuming so, it's a tiny gif - remind me where the size config is?

Comment: @Cjueden, it's obviously less than 15kb

Comment: @Adnan just snagging the low hanging fruit is all. The best place to hide is right in front of the person looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work... I knew it was something small.  Don't forget the boundaries include two extra --'s to split correctly.